# Creating ListItems using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

My task is to create list items using REST. I used this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
createListItemWithDetails('TestList', 'http://sp20139:85', 'TestListRest', function (data) {
    console.log('New task ' + data.d + ' has been created');
}, function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
});
});

function createListItemWithDetails(listName, siteUrl, title, success, failure) {
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": title
};
 $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {    
console.log(data);
        success(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {           
        failure(data);
    }
});
}
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

I checked it in the browser console and it runs successfully.

But the problem is that it didn't show any changes in TestList in SP environment.

Comment: Could you check with Fiddler that response from the REST call do you get?

Comment: yes i did that but didn't work

Comment: What does it mean "works successfully"? Does it print the message "'New task ... has been created'" in the console?

Comment: How did you run the JavaScript code into Console Application?

Comment: Hey hardik,i meant console.log in browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two leads I guess.

First, you may miss authorization Header, but it depends of your list security settings, like for example :

```
headers: {
        ...
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + UserOrAppToken
        ...
    }
```

But more likely, I usually also think ContentLength is mandatory :

```
...
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
contentLength: XXXX,
data: JSON.stringify(item),
...
```

Were XXXX is the length of your item variable

```
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": title
};
```